# WordPress: How to insert texts and images into divs defined in template?

Tags: wordpress

Say, I have a template index.HTML and style.CSS, defining two divs - div A and div B.

Using this template, I want to create three pages - page 1, page 2, and page 3 (not three posts, but three pages).

Since these three pages are based on one same template, they will have the same design, which is the two divs. However, each page needs to have different texts and images inserted into the divs.

Now I have the template ready, but am at a loss how to assign contents into the divs.

When I create page 1, 2, or 3 by "add a new page", I do not see a way to assign texts and images to the divs defined in the template.

I know I can assign different texts and images to different pages in the template by creating three empty pages and adding some codes to the template itself (such as conditional tags), but I cannot take this approach. I should write the contents (texts and images) in the "add a new page" screen and assign the texts and images to the div A and div B respectively.

Anyone can shed me some light?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see the answer i posted ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to understand that this is not like loading of `index.html`when you create a new page from `Add new page`. There's a totally different concept of Page Templates in Wordpress. Page Template is what you select in Page Attributes section while creating a new Page.

[image]

Now the thing is, if you want to create a new custom page template, you would need to follow the guide available at http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates. E.g a new page template would require creating a new .php page and adding some code like this on top:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: New Template for Page
*/
```

Then that Template will be available in that "Page Attributes" menu when you will create a new page. Regarding your query of div1 and div2, you would have to write that in Add new Page section - select HTML view and there add HTML for that. The css for that will be defined in a separate file which you can include in your page template file while creating it.

Normally, what developers do is offer Shortcodes for layout like if you want 3 colomn layout in your page, developers might have provided options which you can use like:

> [col-1]Something here in first column [/col]
>  [col-2]Something here
>   in second column [/col]
>  [col-3]Something here in Third column
>   [/col]

I know this is not a comprehensive answer but your question is so vast, i cannot cover it here. You need to understand the core wordpress concepts for this.

I hope this helps.